# ¿Cómo puedo solucionar este error comman.pdb no cargado?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, reportviewer, rdlc

Cuando intento exportar a formato PDF desde el botón Exportar menú desplegable y selecciono PDF, la depuración detiene la ejecución de mi aplicación asp.net

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No entiendo por qué dice que mi reportviewer.pdb no está cargado. Esto solo aparece con un informe, tengo otros cinco informes y puedo exportar sin problema pero solo uno en especifico marca el error.

¿Alguien me puede ayudar?

Uso .net Framework 4.6 visual studio 2019 antes tenia Framework 3.5 y al actualizarlo al 4.6 me salio este error.